# Need help with MonoDevelop (solution for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, monodevelop

i try to make a solution with MonoDevelop, but i have some problems. I try to compile empty project, but there the builder shows:

```
Building: tusciasProjektas (Debug|iPhone)

Building Solution tusciasProjektas

Building: tusciasProjektas (Debug|iPhone)
Performing main compilation...

Updating CodeBehind files
Updated 1 CodeBehind files

The reference 'System' is not valid for the target framework of the project.
The reference 'System.Xml' is not valid for the target framework of the project.
The reference 'System.Core' is not valid for the target framework of the project.
Assembly 'monotouch' not found. Make sure that the assembly exists in disk. If the reference is required to build the project you may get compilation errors.
Build failed. Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
```

My computer is standart, with Intel CPU (not mac), it has Leopard X installed. I also installed framework for this and MonoDevelop. Maybe it's problem that i don't have installed  MonoTouchSDK(it's require som user and password, and I can't download it from: http://www.go-mono.com/monotouch-download/monotouch-0.9-20090818-0.pkg ). Is anybody working on that and can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stated on http://mono-project.com/MonoTouch_Beta that you have to fill out the beta participation form to get the SDK.

The MonoTouch team will send you the details to get started.

Comment: Ok, thank's for information. I have already registered, for now i'm waiting the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assembly 'monotouch' not found.
```

You *will* need the MonoTouch framework to develop *using* the MonoTouch framework. The first thing you need to do is get that.

Have you followed the "join the beta" link on the project page? That would be a good place to start if you want an account to download it.

http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch_Beta